# Unable to start Openfire on MAC - Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, android, macos, exception, openfire

I downloaded openfire from here->http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/download-landing.jsp?file=openfire/openfire_3_10_2.dmg

Now to start openFire server I opened `System Preferences` and selected `OpenFire` from there.
Whenever i click on **Start Openfire** Button it does not start, status remains stopped.

Then, I thought of starting this from `Terminal` so, I went to the exact path where openFire is placed and executed the openfire.sh file directly.

I got this error-

> My-iMac:local myusername$ sh /usr/local/openfire/bin/openfire.sh
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/jivesoftware/openfire/starter/ServerStarter : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 51.0
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
>
> at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
>
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

I searched for this error, I got this question->[Could not find main class error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531596/could-not-find-main-class-error) 
where accepted answer says-

> It seems you have compiled it against one version of java and running
>   on another version.

I dont understand what to do, if its a java version problem , i have latest updated version of Java & Openfire both.

Any clue on this will be highly appreciated.
Thanks